# Sort Array By variable in the first then sort it descending order

Tags: java, arrays, swing, sorting, comparator

Hey guys here is my question.
im using JCombobox.
if a student have CB grade in the lesson,it should be appear in the jcombobox first , like that CB AA BA BB CC DC DD FD FF
if student have DD grade it should be shown like that  DD AA BA BB CB CC DC FD FF.

Here all Array members

String[] subset = new String[]{"AA", "BA", "BB", "CB", "CC", "DC", "DD", "FD", "FF"};

if a student have BB grade in the lesson array should be sorted like that BB AA BA BB CB CC DC DD FD FF. these mean array should be sorted by student grade in the first element of array. then it should be sorted by descending order.

i asked sorting arrray because jcombobox work on that.
is there a function or method which do that ?

thanks.

Comment: The sorting criteria is not clear, at all. Please explain better what you need, and show several examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static String[] getCustomSortArray(String grade, String[] grades)
{
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        if(grades[i].equals(grade))
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(index == -1) return grades;

    String temp = new String[grades.length];
    temp[0] = grades[index];

    int counter = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        if(i != index) temp[counter++] = grades[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I didn't test it, but I think it works.

Comment: im trying to test your methods but eclipse giving me null pointer exceptions. trying to work it out

Comment: Thanks i finally get it workink you cool man :D :D i have not enough repetion to  vote you up. Whenever i have 15 rep,i will rep you thanks so much

Comment: @user1091692 You're welcome and you can at least accept this answer by checking the right mark :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for sorting the elements in an array according to a given [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), in this case you'll need to craft the comparator to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

for sorting array you can use, it uses compareTo() method of Comparable interface for sorting.

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

For descending sorting you can use `Collections.reverseOrder()` comparator.

If I understand you right this comparator can work for you.

```
        Object yourComparator = new Comparator<Comparable<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Comparable<Object> c1, Comparable<Object> c2) {
                if(c1.equals(variable)){
                    return 1;
                }
                else if(c2.equals(variable)){
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return c2.compareTo(c1);
                }

            }



        };
```

Comment: i want to sort firstly by variable then descinding order.

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'variable'? What variable?

Comment: CB is first variable here :if a student have CB grade in the lesson,it should be appear in the jcombobox first , like that CB AA BA BB CC DC DD FD FF if student have DD grade DD is first variable here: it should be shown like that DD AA BA BB CB CC DC FD FF.

Comment: Thanks for that but im new on Java. It is hard for me to understand your code can you give some example that it shows how to work your method.I mean how can i use compare function. Must i have to give it two objects?